# Renaming column names in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rename

I have the following table as input:

**INPUT**

| Column1.ab.gz | Column2.ab.gz | Column3.ab.gz | Column4.ab.gz | Column5.ab.gz | Column6.ab.gz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 | 22 | 33 | 5 | 7 |
| 1235 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 234 |
| 1236 | 9 | 2 | 82 | 0 | 66 |
| 1237 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1238 | 7 | 11 | 6 | 66 | 1 |
| 1239 | 5 | 27 | 5 | 0 | 8 |
| 1240 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1241 | 15 | 0 | 2 | 13 | 5 |

I would like to rename the column name without 'ab.gz' automatically rather than renaming the column manually (`data.rename(columns = 'Column1.ab.gz' :'Column1', 'Column2.ab.gz' :'Column2', 'Column3.ab.gz' :'Column3', 'Column4.ab.gz' :'Column4', 'Column5.ab.gz' :'Column5', 'Column6.ab.gz' :'Column6')`) since the original table contains 50 columns.
I would also like to remove the row which have all column value as 0.

The output should look something like the following:

**OUTPUT**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 | 22 | 33 | 5 | 7 |
| 1235 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 234 |
| 1236 | 9 | 2 | 82 | 0 | 66 |
| 1238 | 7 | 11 | 6 | 66 | 1 |
| 1239 | 5 | 27 | 5 | 0 | 8 |
| 1241 | 15 | 0 | 2 | 13 | 5 |

How do I do that in python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by empty string:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.ab.gz', '')
print (df)
  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6
0      aa        0       22       33        5        7
1      bb        1        2        2        0      234
2      cc        9        2       82        0       66
3      ee        0        0        0        0        0
4      ff        7       11        6       66        1
5      dd        5       27        5        0        8
6      aa        0        0        0        0        0
7      bb       15        0        2       13        5
```

If need values before first `.`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` like this:

```
df.columns=[i.replace('.ab.gz','') for i in df.columns]
```